# Стиль CardView в kitkat Android 4.4

Tags: android, cardview

Начиная с 21 версии API все впорядке отображается как надо, но в 19 и ниже CardView имеет поля. Как стилизовать, чтобы убрать их?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Попробуйте `app:useCompatPadding=false` прописать в разметке для карточки